# react-reveal animation library firing only once and playing once

Tags: reactjs, scroll, scrollreveal.js

I am trying to add a scroll reveal animation, and found this library useful, react-reveal. But I couldn't find a way to trigger the animation when rereturn to the element's scroll position after scrolling away from the element to animate. I mean while scrolling, the element animates once and never again. Inside documents, I couldnt find a way to handle this.
Any ideas?

```
import  Fade  from 'react-reveal/Fade';
...    
   <Fade left>
     <h1>React Reveal</h1>
   </Fade>
```